# Diamond Operator; initialize paremeterized generic class

Tags: java, generics, collections, initialization

Very often one needs a quick collection of values to be able to iterate over it. Instead of manually creating the instance, adding items or doing the well known constructor-initialization that creates a set out of a list out of an array (`Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.AsList("a", "b", "c"))`) I wanted to create a function that should do the job for me.

Beside the Fact, that I want to provide the generic parameter `<S>` to use for the collection-class, i also want to provide the generic parameter `<T>` - the actual type of the `Collection`.

So, my first approach was the following:

```
public static <T extends Collection<S>, S> T initializeCollection(Class<T> concreteClass, S... objects) {
    T result;

    try {
        result = concreteClass.newInstance();
        for (S s : objects) {
            result.add(s);
        }

        return result;
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This works quite well and could be used like:

```
LinkedList<String> myList = StaticHelper.initializeCollection(LinkedList.class, "a", "b");
```

or

```
HashSet<Integer> mySet = StaticHelper.initializeCollection(HashSet.class, 1,2,3,4,5);
```

from what I tested by now this works as expected. The only problem is that the validator states, that theres an unsave type conversion going on. Using the Example of the Set, the validator says

```
 Type safety: The expression of type HashSet needs unchecked conversion to conform to HashSet<Integer>
```

When I look closer at the return value the IDE is stating for my function it looks like this:

```
 <HashSet, Integer> HashSet my.namespace.helper.CollectionHelper.initializeCollection(Class<HashSet> concreteClass, Integer... objects)
```

Therefore the validator ofc thinks, that he has to do a unsave cast from `HashSet` to `HashSet<Integer>`.

But in my opinion, the return value of the function is `T`, which is pretty much defined as `Collection<S>` - and not as `Collection`.

Now i'm wondering if:

- There is an Issue with my function, and *really* an unsave typecast happening
- There is an Issue with the IDE, not showing the correct returnValue and therefore the validater couldn't do it's job properly.

**Sidenode:**
Even if a good *alternative* has been posted (which i am already using) i'm quite interested in the *solution* to this problem.

```
public static <T extends Collection<S>, S> T<S> initializeCollection ...
```

or using

```
... initializeCollection(HashSet<Integer>.class,...
```

is obviously invalid syntax, but basically *would look like* whats required.

Comment: I think the problem is that there is no way for the compiler to get the generic information from the `.class` literal. Therefore I don't think it is possible to do it this way without a warning.

Answer (score 3):

Not really a direct answer but you could make it simpler with:

```
@SafeVarargs
public static <T extends Collection<S>, S> T initializeCollection(T collection, S... objects) {
    Collections.addAll(collection, objects);
    return collection;
}
```

And call it with:

```
HashSet<Integer> mySet = initializeCollection(new HashSet<>(), 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Comment: Thats pretty nice also. Also the validator likes this approach. :)

Comment: no warning (with the SafeVarargs annotation). I think your problem is that `result = concreteClass.newInstance();` returns a raw type so I don't think you can get rid of the warning easily...

Comment: lso without that annotation I have no warnings.

Comment: @dognose without the annotation I get `Possible heap pollution from parameterized vararg type S`

Comment: I think this is preferable anyway, because you don't have the exception / null problem.